# Heavy HDD access even without swap (Lubuntu)

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, ram

**L**ubuntu 18.04, default desktop configuration.

I turn the swap off and begin a RAM stress test.

When I allocate too much RAM, the system starts to read or write something constantly, completely freezes and requires a hard reset.

What exactly is happening? What data it reads or writes, and why does it freeze it completely?

I understand the system *may* freeze when it runs out of memory, the question is why my hard drive is so busy? Does it drops/re-reads the disk cache? Ext nodes? Something else?

And how exactly /proc/sys/vm/admin_reserve_kbytes affect this problem (if I increase it, this happens less and less often)?

Comment: No matter how I allocate RAM. It can even be a memory-hungry application (with a single exception: a lua script which does not freeze the system, but simply repots a memory allocation error). All other tests lead to either OOM killer (which is obviously OK) or this mysterious freeze. I'm not asking how to prevent it. The question is, why this freeze always(!) make my HDD gallop. It either does not happen at all (OOM killer works instead) or, if it happens, it's never silent. My hard drive works like crazy. Why? There are no swap on this drive, so why it goes gallop?

Comment: The question makes more sense after the edit. I am retracting the close vote.

Comment: Language barrier, sorry ^__^

Comment: The best I could find: complicated software suffers from lack of RAM. If too much code buffer space is cleared, kernel begins to execute code directly from HDD too often. It's OK if we're slowly processing a long and linear code, because we're working with a tiny part and load another one from HDD at time, but it's not OK if we're jumping between thousands of such chunks. After increasing /proc/sys/vm/admin_reserve_kbytes according to modern bloatware structure, I've got _significant_ improvement of stability. What /proc/sys/vm/admin_reserve_kbytes is exactly for?

Comment: In my experience, Linux is extremely unpredictable when there isn't enough memory, and freeze ups in this case are common, particularly when the oom-killer comes into play. I wouldn't disable swap if you're resource constrained. If you want further specifics on what is utilizing disk I/O and memory, I'd implement something like `sar` or `iostat` from the `sysstat` packages to help you drill down into what is causing the undesirable high utilization of the disk.
I'd check dmesg, /var/log/messages, and journalctl -b immediately following a crash as well.